# When combine TCPServer with ThreadingMixIn, it block

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

the server-side code  (tcp_server.py):

```
from SocketServer import TCPServer, ThreadingMixIn, StreamRequestHandler

class Server(ThreadingMixIn, TCPServer):
    pass

class Handler(StreamRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        print 'got a connection from: ', self.request.getpeername()
        print self.rfile.read(1024)
        msg = 'hello'
        self.wfile.write(msg)

server = Server(('127.0.0.1', 8888), Handler)
server.serve_forever()
```

the client-side code  (tcp_client.py):

```
from socket import *
import threading

def do_connection():
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8888))
    s.sendall('this is client')
    print s.recv(1024)

ts = []

for x in xrange(100):
    print x
    t = threading.Thread(target=do_connection())
    t.daemon = True
    ts.append(t)

for t in ts:
    t.start()
```

I runned `tcp_server.py`, and then `tcp_client.py`. `tcp_client.py` should have been over soon. However, `tcp_client.py` seemed just run only one thread and blocked, and `tcp_server.py`  got only one connection.  When I interrupted `tcp_client.py`，`tcp_server.py` got one message `this is client`。

Is there any mistake in my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=do_connection())
```

Should be

```
t = threading.Thread(target=do_connection)
```

When you use `do_connection()`, you end up executing `do_connection` in the main thread, and then pass the return value of that call to the `Thread` object. What you want to do is pass the `do_connection` function object to `Thread`, so that the `Thread` object can execute `do_connection` in a new thread when you call `t.start`.

Also, note that starting 100 threads concurrently to connect to your server may not perform very well. You may want to consider starting with fewer threads, and working your way up to a higher number once you know things are working properly.

Answer (score 0):

because the server is blocked by the first request, I try to change the read(1024) to 
readline in the server.py and add a '\n' to the content sended from the client, it 
works.

it seems the rfile.read(1024) will block the how process, so the goodway is use readline
or use the self.request.recv(1024)

server.py

```
from SocketServer import TCPServer, ThreadingMixIn, StreamRequestHandler

class Server(ThreadingMixIn, TCPServer):
    pass

class Handler(StreamRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        print 'got a connection from: ', self.request.getpeername()
        print self.rfile.readline()
        #print self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        msg = 'hello'
        self.wfile.write(msg)


# Create the server, binding to localhost on port 9999
server = Server(("127.0.0.1", 8888), Handler)
server.serve_forever()
```

client.py

```
from socket import *
import threading

def do_connection():
    print "start"
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8888))
    s.sendall('this is client\n')
    print s.recv(1024)

ts = []

for x in xrange(100):
    print x
    t = threading.Thread(target=do_connection)
    ts.append(t)

for t in ts:
    print "start t"
    t.start()
```

Comment: I forgot another problem which @dano answered.